# Is there a way to enter the debugger on an error?

Tags: debugging, powershell, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to enter the PowerShell debugger in response to an error? The `ErrorAction` parameter has several values but I don't see anything like `Debug`. What I would like is to open the debugger like it would open if I had set a breakpoint, but only when an error occurs (from, say, `Write-Error`).

**Edit**
I should clarify a bit: I am primarily a C# developer and somewhat new to PowerShell, what I am expecting is behavior similar to what the Visual Studio debugger gives you for "unhandled exceptions". It appears that it is more common for PowerShell commands to throw exceptions, while custom scripts seem to mostly use Write-Error. I don't think I particularly care to distinguish between the two, but I would like to handle both.

Trevor Sullivan's answer below mentions that you can use `Set-PSBreakpoint -Command Write-Error -Action { break; };` which appears to work well to catch those cases. Though, I am finding that in many cases it is actually a command throwing an exception that I would like to break on. Roman Kuzmin's answer appears to work if you set `$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"`, however, I have the problem that I cannot step through the program, it seems to break out of that location and end the script. If `$ErrorActionPreference = "continue"` it does not work for me. Traps in general seem to have a similar issue that they break out out of any nested scopes, which is not desired.

Comment: Great question - just posted an answer, complete with example.

Answer (score 28):

Of course. You can create conditional breakpoints in PowerShell, using the `Set-PSBreakpoint` cmdlet. Consider the following code. Save it as a script file, and execute it. There are in-line comments to help you understand what's going on.

Keep in mind that there are three different types of breakpoints:

- Line
- Variable
- Command

### Command Breakpoint

This code example is using the command breakpoint type, because I am telling it to only set breakpoints on `Get-WmiObject` commands. You can alternately specify a specific line number or a variable breakpoint type. You use the `-Action` parameter to specify the conditions under which you want the breakpoint to be set. You must use the `break` keyword somewhere inside the `-Action` `ScriptBlock` in order to instruct the debugger to pause execution of the PowerShell script.

```
# 1. Reset $Error to $null
$WmiError = $null;

# 2. Clean up any existing breakpoints
Get-PSBreakpoint | Remove-PSBreakpoint;

# 3. Set breakpoint, but only on Get-WmiObject commands, when the $WmiError variable is not $null
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command Get-WmiObject -Action { if ($WmiError) { break; } };

# 4. Failed Get-WmiObject command
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NonExistentClass -ErrorVariable WmiError;

# 5. Successful Get-WmiObject command
#    PowerShell breaks here, because:
#     - It's a Get-WmiObject command
#     - The $WmiError variable is not null
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS;
```

Since you mentioned using `Write-Error`, you could set a `PSBreakpoint` on lines where `Write-Error` appears. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command Write-Error -Action { break; };
```

Pretty easy, right?

### Variable Breakpoint

This example uses the variable `PSBreakpoint` type, but only when the variable's contents are modified. You can use the `-Mode` parameter to determine under what conditions the variable breakpoint is hit:

- Read
- ReadWrite
- Write

Code:

```
# 1. Clean up any existing breakpoints
Get-PSBreakpoint | Remove-PSBreakpoint;

# 2. Set a PSBreakpoint of type "variable" on a variable named "Data," but only when it has changed
Set-PSBreakpoint -Action { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object ('The $Data variable has changed! Value is: {0}' -f $Data); break; } -Variable Data -Mode Write;

# 3. No break on this line, because we are not changing the variable
Write-Host -Object $Data;

# 4. Execution is paused on this line, because we change the variable
$Data = 1;
```

### Line Breakpoint

Now that we've looked at the **variable** and **command** `PSBreakpoint` types, the last type of breakpoint to explore is the **line** breakpoint. If you were to copy/paste the code below, save it, and execute it, you would see that the code breaks on the Write-Host line (which happens to be line 9), but only when the `Name` property of the `$Service` variable is equal to `WinRM`. That is what the conditional statement in the `-Action` parameter's `ScriptBlock` defines.

```
# 1. Clean up any existing breakpoints
Get-PSBreakpoint | Remove-PSBreakpoint;

# 2. Set a PSBreakpoint of type "line" on line #8, but only if the $Service variable's Name property equals 'winrm'
Set-PSBreakpoint -Action { if ($Service.Name -eq 'winrm') { break; } } -Line 9 -Script $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;

# 3. Get a list of Windows Services and iterate over them
foreach ($Service in (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service)) {
    Write-Host -Object ('Service name is: {0}' -f $Service.Name);
}
```

Comment: Seems archaic, but thank you for your clear explanations.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, there is a simple way to break into the debugger on errors. It looks like
each time when an error happens the variable `StackTrace` gets updated. So I
use this trick: in my profile I have these two functions (switches):

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Sets $StackTrace breakpoint
.Link
    rbps
#>
function sbps {
    $null = Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable StackTrace -Mode Write
}

<#
.Synopsis
    Removes $StackTrace breakpoint
.Link
    sbps
#>
function rbps {
    Get-PSBreakpoint -Variable StackTrace | Remove-PSBreakpoint
}
```

When the first is called then breaking into the debugger on errors is actually
enabled. On errors `StackTrace` is written and this triggers the breakpoint.

The second function turns breaking into the debugger on errors off.

In most cases this approach works for me just fine.

---

**UPDATE**

In order to use this technique without profile functions a helper script like
[Debug-Error.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Debug-Error.ps1)
can be used. Ideally, it should should be located in the path, so that commands
`Debug-Error` and `Debug-Error -Off` are always available.

See also this [blog post](http://nightroman.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/enable-debugging-on-terminating-errors/).

---

A few related tickets on Connect:

- [342346](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/342346/yet-another-option-choice-debug-for-actionpreference-and-inquire-prompt)
- [637838](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/637838/add-break-option-to-preference-variables)
- [741732](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/741732/need-support-for-break-on-error)

Comment: It would still be far better if PowerShell ISE integrated this properly. For example, after hitting your breakpoint, you have to manually run Step Into to actually get the error to occur: this breakpoint travels back in time to before the error was raised! However, it's probably all we have so far, so thank you — at least it makes PowerShell slightly less insufferable.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a function that sets a breakpoint on a variable, then changes the value of the variable.

```
function Debug-Here {
    if(!(Get-PSBreakpoint -Variable DebugHereCount)) {
        $SCRIPT:DebugHere= Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable DebugHereCount
    }
    $DebugHereCount++
}
```

Then call the function from a trap a the top of the script to catch all terminating errors.

```
trap { Debug-Here }
```

Or call it from a `try-catch` statement.

```
Get-Item DoesNotExist.txt -ErrorAction Stop

try {
    $x = 0
    $y = 1/$x
}
catch {
    Debug-Here
}
```

Once you are in debug mode, check `$Error[0]` to see what triggered the breakpoint.

Comment: This is great. I want to implement a BreakIf function that takes a scriptblock argument. The script determines whether to take the breakpoint. With a line breakpoint the BreakIf script would have to know which line number within itself to set the bp on. And this gives me another idea: use Get-PSCallStack to find the line number in the caller to set a break on. That way the break occurs right after the BreakIf instead of inside the BreakIf

Answer (score 2):

Kinda hokey but works on write-error or throw statements:

```
$error.clear()
$global:errcnt=0
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command * -action {if ($error.count -ne $global:errcnt) {$global:errcnt=$error.count;break}}
```

Comment: Not bad, but causes the break after the error has occurred, which means that the current line is usually in a try/catch block (and thus out of scope)