# Can I "break when an exception is thrown" in Windows Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Can I do this in the Powershell ISE like I can in Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio Break On Exception Options]

Obviously I am not expecting the same dialogue and I'd hazard a guess I can wrap a try/catch around the part which calls out to the offending (nested) scripts - the bit of stuff I am interested in is nested deep.  Id also assume that I can either go and open the existing file and slap a breakpoint in there.

However in the absence of doing that and as a nice convenience I would just like to be able to "break on any exception" because I am lazy.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20912371/323582. I use the solution with *Debug-Error.ps1*, see one of the answers (mine).

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell there are automatic variables

The one you want to adjust is $ErrorActionPreference

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
```

Now when you hit any error within a commands that supports the -ErrorAction switch, the script will stop. It is worth noting that this is a native PowerShell action and you will still need the Try\Catch for any .NET and C# commands

Comment: I will give this a whirl

Comment: It sounds like the answer is no.  'Stop' will stop the script and you're have to start again from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

@beehaus is on the right track, but with the wrong value. [$ErrorActionPreference should be set to "break", per the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#erroractionpreference)

"Break - Enter the debugger when an error occurs or when an exception is raised."

aka

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Break"
```