# powershell, start debugger in case of an error

Tags: powershell, debugging

If I set a breakpoint in a script on a line/ variable modification/ command, the debugger fires as soon this condition reached. Is it possible to have the debugger fires in case of an error ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20913821/323582

Comment: thanks a lot Roman Kuzmin. I was not aware of the StackTrace variable. if you add this as an answer instead of a comment I will validate it.

Comment: I cannot, SO converts "trivial answers" to comments. But I can mark your question as duplicate, so that it is clear where to go.

Comment: yes please, mark the question as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire the debugger on an error you've got five CmdLets :

```
Get-Command -Noun "psbreakpoint"

CommandType    Name                  
-----------    ----                  
Cmdlet         Disable-PSBreakpoint  
Cmdlet         Enable-PSBreakpoint   
Cmdlet         Get-PSBreakpoint      
Cmdlet         Remove-PSBreakpoint   
Cmdlet         Set-PSBreakpoint
```

You can start using `Set-PSBreakpoint` to set your brekpoint and so on.

Comment: read more carefully my question. I'm already aware of these command, otherwise how would I set breakpoints on script line, variable modification or command...

Comment: You have to call these CmdLet on Exceptions `using` trap or `try/catch`.

Comment: I don't think so but I may be wrong. please provide us an example